# What does losing innocence mean on Lost?

Tags: lost

In *Lost* S5E11, "Whatever Happened, Happened", and following the events of the previous episode, James Ford (Sawyer) and Kate Austin decide to take young Benjamin Linus who was shot by Sayid Jarrah to "The Others" in order to heal him.

When they encounter Richard Alpert, he warns them that if he treats Ben, he (Ben) will "lose his innocence". What does that exactly mean?

Video of the scene:

Comment: Not seen Lost but a potentially important clarification: is it explicitly stated that he will lose his innocence *as a result of the treatment*, or could an alternative interpretation be that, if treated, he will survive long enough to lose it some other way?

Comment: @tardigrade Given the way this show loved to throw out red herrings and other random vagueries, it's really anyone's guess what they meant.  Given that this is post "game changer" events in S4, odds are probably good that the writers themselves didn't know either.

Comment: Especially given that "loss of innocence" can mean anything from becoming aware of seamy things he was better off not knowing, through becoming complicit in some evil through doing nothing to stop it though being aware of it, to actually doing something evil.

Comment: Basically, that's the general consensus, but why such process would do that? shouldn't healing make you better on all fronts?